# Element.bind registers only every other ng-click :: (AngularJS + Ionic)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an animated hamburger menu icon. Everything is finished and works except the element.bind applies the active class only on every other ng-click (this is the essence of the animation). When I put console.log into the $scope.animateHamburger, it gets printed every time. Please see the code below where I also list what the console log returns.

controllers.js

```
$scope.animateHamburger = function() {
    $scope.button = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('c-hamburger')[0]);

    $scope.button.bind('click', function() {
        $scope.button.toggleClass('is-active');
    });
};
```

html

```
<button class="c-hamburger" ng-click="animateHamburger()" menu-toggle="left">
    <span>toggle menu</span>
</button>
```

css (if needed)

```
/*** Hamburger button ***/
.c-hamburger {
  background: transparent;
  border: none;
  height: 44px;
  position: relative;
  top: -21px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  width: 48px;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
}

.c-hamburger:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.c-hamburger span {
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 9px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 4px;
  top: 21px;
}

.c-hamburger span::before,
.c-hamburger span::after {
  background-color: #fff;
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 2px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;

  transition-duration: 0.3s, 0.3s;
  transition-delay: 0.3s, 0s;
}

.c-hamburger span::before {
  top: -8px;
  transition-property: top, transform;
}

.c-hamburger span::after {
  bottom: -8px;
  transition-property: bottom, transform;
}

/* active state, i.e. menu open */
.c-hamburger.is-active span {
  background: none;
}

.c-hamburger.is-active span::before {
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
      -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
          transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.c-hamburger.is-active span::after {
  bottom: 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
      -ms=transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.c-hamburger.is-active span::before,
.c-hamburger.is-active span::after {
  transition-delay: 0s, 0.3s;
}
/* Hamburger button */
```

console.log inside of $scope.animateHamburger after 4 successive clicks

```
Object { 0: <button.c-hamburger>, length: 1 } controllers.js
Object { 0: <button.c-hamburger>, length: 1 } controllers.js
Object { 0: <button.c-hamburger.is-active>, length: 1 } controllers.js
Object { 0: <button.c-hamburger.is-active>, length: 1 } controllers.js
```

Comment: From what I understand you have there a few elements that would match the selector `document.querySelectorAll('.c-hamburger')`, right?

Comment: There is only one element, and that is the one I included in my html. Now I am looking at it, perhaps the log shouldn't show length: 2 then?

Comment: Yes. That is why I asked if you have or not other elements to satisfy this selector.

Comment: I simplified it, but the problem still persists .. :(

Comment: One more question, why do you need to do this binding? Given your html, you can just do use ng-class which allows to evaluate an expresion and apply one or another css class, and for ng-click just do `ng-click="isActive = !isActive"`. And the ng-class will have to evaluate just `isActive:...`

Comment: Brilliant, that does it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what should solve your issue:

```
<button ng-class="{'is-active': isActive, 'c-hamburger c-hamburger--htx': !isActive}" ng-click="isActive = !isActive" menu-toggle="left">
```

And no additional code is needed in controller.

Comment: Yes that did it, thanks! Sometimes I overthink it too much

Comment: We all do that sometimes :)